# Challenge-Response Phases in IND-CPA

Tags: chosen-plaintext-attack

The IND-CPA game has two challenge-response phases

1. A key is generated by running $Gen(1^n)$ and challenger selects a bit
   b {0,1} uniformly at random.
2. Adversary gets input $1^n$.
3. Can query the oracle a polynomial number of times with messages and gets $E_k(m)$ back.
4. Attacker sends messages $m_0$, $m_1$, challenger returns $E_k(m_b)$.
5. Can query the oracle a polynomial number of times with messages and gets $E_k(m)$ back.

Why are these two challenge-response phases (3,5) necessary? I understand why at least one phase is necessary (ex: to ensure that deterministic algorithms are not IND-CPA secure), but why both?

Comment: Don't forget to select an answer *if* one of the responses sufficiently answers your question. If not, could you indicate what's missing?

Answer (score 4):

You need to allow queries before the attacker outputs $m_0,m_1$ since maybe the queries help the attacker choose $m_0,m_1$ that are "easier" for it to attack.

You need to allow queries after the attacker receives back the challenge ciphertext $c=E_k(m_b)$ since knowing $c$ may make it possible to generate a plaintext whose encryption helps to know what $c$ is.

Answer (score 0):

The oracle in step 3 is absolutely necessary. Check [the answer to this question](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/30186/security-game-oracle-queries) for an example that would break IND-CPA security otherwise.

On the other hand, the oracle in step 5 may be unnecessary for IND-CPA security according to the alternate formulations of IND-CPA suggested in [the CRYPTUTOR wiki](http://crypto.cs.uiuc.edu/wiki/index.php/IND-CPA_security#Modifications) from UIUC.

Comment: As the author of that wiki page, I wouldn't take it as definitive. Maybe I had thought about it quite carefully when writing it, but my intuition seeing it today is that you need encryption queries before and after the challenge ciphertext gets generated.

Comment: Do any of you know some proof of either of the options. I've seen people state that step 5 is not necessary, but I have never seen a proof.

Comment: @thegreat2 As Yehuda Lindell have answered, "knowing $c$ may make it possible to generate a plaintext whose encryption helps to know what $c$ is." So for security definition to include all the case (not special cases), the oracle in step 5 is indeed **necessary**.